# Stm32 hardfault exception at Rtos

Tags: stm32, freertos, stm32f4discovery, stm32f4

[task_create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cw2Ku.png)

[tasks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ua8SC.png)

[rtos_config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYhb0.png)

[debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DeJy.png)

I am new at RTOS , created two tasks on stm32cubeide but i counter    HardFault_Handler exception on debug  . why could it be ? I have the need for    your help . all of the file --> [link](https://s6.dosya.tc/server3/vqq1da/001_HelloWorld_FreeRTOS.rar.html)
thanks....

Comment: Please post code instead of images. And show where is the exception, or at least detail it a bit more.

Comment: I’m pretty sure that the (minimal) task stack size is too small mainly because printf is called, which is known to be quite stack hungry. Increase it (e.g. using > 500) and retry. And more important enable FreeRTOS stack overflow checking and configASSERT for development.

Comment: https://www.freertos.org/Debugging-Hard-Faults-On-Cortex-M-Microcontrollers.html enjoy your Friday night ;)

Answer (score 0):

Normally this happened in RTOS because some task need more memory. Increase stack Size by editing your task.

[image]

If you add a lot of task or use more memory maybe you can overflow default total memory heap allocated in FreeRTOS. You can increase that in the Config Parameter tab.
Remember, more memory allocated by FreeRTOS less free RAM memory.

[image]